# Android HttpWebConnection security

Tags: android, security, session

I am working on an applikation for Android platform. The application uses heavy amounts of HTTP calls to my webserver. This works out verry well but im in need of assistance in securing my calls and webserver.

I know that i can use SSL through Https to encrypt my connection both clientside and serverside, this is not a problem and will ofcourse be done when launching the application. But what would the most secure way be to have a session for the logged in device?

Ive thought about making a mysql based session system containing the following rows

id - sessKey - sessCont - sessUid - sessTime

sessKey will be a random generated 32 bit key. sessCont a JSON array of the stored informations and sessUid will be the user id of the user signed on. sessTime would contain a timestamp.

This session will be set on login and the phone would then recive the sessKey + sessId. When making calls the key will be changed and returned to the phone again. If a call is 10 minutes later than the latest call the session will close down and a new one will have to be made.

Yet i keep seing ways of compromising this approach, as well as i can with all other approches im able to think off.

How would i manage to make the best possible security and session control from my phone to my serverside script?

Thanks in advance.
Jonas

Comment: Um, can you share some ways you feel these methods might be compromised? With an SSL connection, nothing can be intercepted. So are you worried about someone compromising your security from the user's end? If you're going to change the key every time why not just store a userid and passhash and just login every time?

Comment: Im not afraid of the data being read and understood since i will SSL the connection. Im afraid of session hijacks and therefor asking for a way to prevent this and what the most advicerable way to make a session between php and android is.Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright numbered list time...

1. If you're using an SSL connection a good portion of security is already on your side. You can cross sniffing off your list of vulnerabilities.
2. Most of the leftover vulnerability will be on the user end, can hackers monitor the hardware on the user end and grab a session information after it's been transferred to the user's hardware, which in this case is an android phone. App data is protected from other apps so unless you, the developer, or your user is doing something insanely reckless it should be secure.
3. Which leads me to #3, all the rest of the security really lands in your lap as the developer. If you have cross-site scripting (XSS), the session IDs can be guessed easily, or you are vulnerable to session fixation, or your session ID storage is weak (SQL injection?) then you've effectively undone all the good work you did with every other measure of security.

In the end there are always ways to hack a system, but if you follow those three steps you've done everything you can do in order to prevent hackers. The rest unfortunately lies in the parts we can't touch; Android operating system, cell phone networks, user's common sense.

P.S. The most secure method would probably be to trash the session idea. Store the user id (a number that could mean anything), and a md5 encrypted version of their password. Be sure to add something funky so hackers can't just look up the reverse of common passwords. (IE. theirPassword+userid+HACKTHISSUCKERS) and even if someone goes to an md5 reverser they won't be able to undo your hash. And then every time you make a request to your server, do it over SSL and when the authentication checks out, send the info. Secure SSL connection, secure md5 passhash, no security leaks.

Even if a hacker somehow found what your app was sending to your server; a number and a undecipherable hash. The only way they could find out what your app was sending was if your user was being negligent and allowed their phone to be connected to the hacker's hardware that was actually capable of intercepting POST data before it was sent over the SSL connection.